# Discrete PMF -> continuous CDF. How?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working through an example in a textbook where the author is trying to find the PDF of the Cauchy distribution (continuous).

First they declare that $T = X/Y$ is Cauchy, where $X$ and $Y$ are both $N(0,1)$.
That leads to the definition of $T$'s CDF which we want to find as follows:

$$F_T(t)=P(X\le t|Y|)$$

Great. Now they're using LOTP to actually find the CDF. They declare an indicator random variable for the event $X \le t|Y|$, ie it's $1$ if the above equation holds true.

Then comes the part I don't get. They somehow magically go from a conditional PMF for $I$ to CDF for $t|y|$:

\begin{align}
P(I=1) & =\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(I=1\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\,dy \\[8pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2} \Phi(t|y|) \, dy
\end{align}

How did they do that? I'm at the "Introduction to Probability" level, so some intuition + simple explanation would be best!

Comment: Notice that $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be **independent**. By law of total probability, $P(X\le t|Y|)=\int P(X\le t|y|\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\,dy=\int P(X\le t|y|)f_Y(y)\,dy=\int\Phi(t|y|)f_Y(y)\,dy$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(I=1\mid Y=y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr( X\le t|Y|\,\,\mid Y=y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(X\le t|y|) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Phi(t|y|)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, the point I missed before was that because X and Y are independent, the conditional probability P(A|B) can be reduced to P(A)!

Answer (score 0):

In general if $(Z,Y)$ have a joint distribution and marginal $Y$ has a PDF $f_Y$ then under suitable conditions:$$\mathbb EZ=\int\mathbb E[Z\mid Y=y]f_Y(y)\;dy$$

In the special case where $Z$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ we also have $\mathbb EZ=P(Z=1)$ and $\mathbb E[Z\mid Y=y]=P(Z=1\mid Y=y)$ leading to:$$P(Z\mid Y=y)=\int P(Z=1\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\;dy$$